# Does converting integers with underscores throw silent errors?

Tags: ruby, integer

I was working on an exercise earlier today, and it involved summing all the digits in a given integer. One of these digits had underscores.

I decided to try and *not* use a regex to only catch the numbers. Instead, I simply converted the integer to a string, use an each_char loop to grab each char, and push it to a new array while converting to an integer.

However, it seems that it ignores the underscores (and, perhaps, rightly so). Maybe I'm thinking of this incorrectly, but it's my understanding that an underscore is not an integer.

So, during the push/conversion process, is Ruby throwing a silent error somewhere, which makes it ignore the underscore and continue unimpeded? If so, is there a way to catch and view this error?

Here is the code I'm talking about.

```
def summed_digits2(int)
  num_arr = []
  int.to_s.each_char {|x| num_arr.push(x.to_i)}
  num_arr.reduce(:+)
end

puts summed_digits2(123_456_789)
```

Comment: See Ruby's documentation on [Number literals](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Numbers): _"The underscore may be used to enhance readability for humans"_

Answer (score 3):

`'123_456_789'` is a string that contains digits and underscores. You can use `regex` or string processing functions to ignore the underscores and process only the digit-resembling characters.

`123_456_789` is a number. It is the same as `123456789`. It is also the same as `0x75bcd15`. Its value is the same, even if it is written in different ways. It can be, as well, written using [Roman numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals) but its value is still `123456789`.
*(The Ruby parser **does not** understand Roman numerals. The statement is used here just to emphasize the idea.)*

There are no underscores in a number because a number is not a string. It is [an amount, a quantity, a concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number), no matter how it is written on paper or in computer programs.

---

Back to your problem, let's remark that "the sum of digits" depends on the way the number is represented. Most of the times it is written using the usual 10 base and this is how we'll use it here.

There are many ways to compute the sum of digits of a given number. My favorite:

```
123_456_789.to_s.chars.map(&:to_i).inject(:+)
```

How it works:

```
123_456_789           # this is a number: 123456789
    .to_s             # convert to string: "123456789"
    .chars            # split to an array of chars: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
    .map(&:to_i)      # convert each array item to number: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    .inject(:+)       # "inject" the addition operator ("+") between the items and compute: 45
```

Comment: Although Ruby's parser recognizes `123_456_789` and `0x75bcd15` as 123456789, it cannot parse roman numerals. Saying that it can be written that way might be confusing.

Comment: @Stefan your remark is correct and useful. I mentioned in the answer that the Ruby parser cannot parse Roman numerals.

Comment: @axiac But you can easily [add this](https://gist.github.com/meineerde/3c8dfe497aa616bfaef2af6d41895322) too :)

Answer (score 2):

Underscores are just a facilitation for the developer, underlying numbers have no underscores.

A simple solution for your exercise

```
def summed_digits2(int)
  int.to_s.chars.map(&:to_i).inject(:+)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Other answers are good. I'll just point out that ruby 2.4 brings `Integer#digits` and `Enumerable#sum`.

```
123_456_789.digits # => [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
123_456_789.digits.sum # => 45
```